# Drawing a SuperEllipse in HLSL

Tags: c#, math, hlsl, ellipse

**Update : answer on how to draw one using Superformula is at the end**

I need to draw a rounded rectangle such as this one, using a [SuperEllipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).
[image]

Drawing one when being able to plot wherever was easy :

[image]

But in HLSL where you cannot, I got stuck on the condition for plotting or not a pixel :

[image]

Here is the HLSL code :

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>10.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>4.0</defaultValue>
float N : register(C1);

static const float pi = 3.1415926535f;

float2 superEllipse(float n, float a, float b, float theta)      
{
    float ct = cos(theta);
    float st = sin(theta);
    float x = a * sign(ct) * pow(abs(ct), 2.0f / n);
    float y = b * sign(st) * pow(abs(st), 2.0f / n);
    return float2(x, y);
}

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{
    float2 uv1 = uv * float2(2.0f, 2.0f) - float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    float angle = degrees(atan2(uv1.y, uv1.x)) + 180.0f;
    float tMax = pi * 2.0f;
    float theta = 1.0f / 360.0f * angle * tMax;
    float2 se = superEllipse(N, 1, 1, theta);
    float angle1 = degrees(atan2(se.y, se.x)) + 180.0f;
    float2 zero = float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    float dist1 = distance(se, zero);
    float dist2 = distance(uv1, zero);

    float4 color = float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    if(dist2 <= dist1)
        color += float4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    return color;

}
```

Error seems to be with 'dist1' and 'dist2' variables.

(Created with [Shazzam](http://shazzam-tool.com/))

Here's the working C# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            const double halfPi = Math.PI*2.0d;
            double nValue = trackBar1.Value/10.0d;
            double aValue = trackBar2.Value/100.0d;
            double bValue = trackBar3.Value/100.0d;
            label1.Text = nValue.ToString("F2");
            label2.Text = aValue.ToString("F2");
            label3.Text = bValue.ToString("F2");
            double n = nValue;
            double a = aValue;
            double b = bValue;

            // Build list of points
            const int points = 100;
            const double step = 360.0d/points;
            var list = new List<PointF>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= points; i++)
            {
                double angle = step*i;
                double t = 1.0d/360.0d*angle;
                double theta = t*halfPi;
                double x;
                double y;
                SuperEllipse.Evaluate(n, a, b, theta, out x, out y);
                list.Add(new PointF((float) x, (float) y));
            }

            /* Drawing */
            // Scale and center
            for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
            {
                PointF pointF = list[index];
                pointF.X++;
                pointF.Y++;
                pointF.X *= (pictureBox1.Width - 10)/2f;
                pointF.Y *= (pictureBox1.Height - 10)/2f;
                pointF.X += 5;
                pointF.Y += 5;
                list[index] = pointF;
            }
            // Draw and show
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                //graphics.TranslateTransform(1, 1);
                graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, list.ToArray());
                // graphics.FillClosedCurve(Brushes.Red, fs, FillMode.Alternate);
            }
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Run();
        }

        private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Run();
        }

        private void trackBar3_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Run();
        }
    }

    public static class SuperEllipse
    {
        public static void Evaluate(double n, double a, double b, double theta, out double x, out double y)
        {
            double cost = Math.Cos(theta);
            double sint = Math.Sin(theta);
            x = a*Math.Sign(cost)*Math.Pow(Math.Abs(cost), 2.0d/n);
            y = b*Math.Sign(sint)*Math.Pow(Math.Abs(sint), 2.0d/n);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

SuperFormula in HLSL (still not right)
[image]

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.0</defaultValue>
float A : register(C0);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.0</defaultValue>
float B : register(C1);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.0</defaultValue>
float M : register(C2);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0, 0.0, 0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0, 8.0, 8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.0, 1.0, 1.0</defaultValue>
float3 N : register(C3);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{
    float2 uv1 = uv * float2(2.0f, 2.0f) - float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    float angle = degrees(atan2(uv1.y, uv1.x)) + 180.0f;
    float mt = M * angle / 4.0f;
    float magnitude = pow((pow((cos(mt) / A), N.y) + pow((sin(mt) / B), N.z)), -(1.0f / N.x));
    float2 zero = float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    float dist1 = distance(uv1, zero);
    float4 color = float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    if(dist1 <= magnitude)
        color += float4(dist1, 1, 0, 1);
    return color;
}
```

Finally, a rounded rectangle using [Superformula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula) thanks to Kevin :

[image]

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.0</defaultValue>
float A : register(C0);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.0</defaultValue>
float B : register(C1);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>8.0</defaultValue>
float M : register(C2);

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.0, 0.0, 0.0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>8.0, 8.0, 8.0</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.0, 1.0, 1.0</defaultValue>
float3 N : register(C3);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{
    float2 uv1 = uv * float2(2.0f, 2.0f) - float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    float angle = atan2(uv1.y, uv1.x);
    float mt = M * angle / 4.0f;
    float magnitude = pow((pow((abs(cos(mt)) / A), N.y) + pow((abs(sin(mt)) / B), N.z)), -(1.0f / N.x));
    float2 zero = float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    float dist1 = distance(uv1, zero);
    float4 color = float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    float alpha = 1.0f / magnitude * dist1;
    if(dist1 <= magnitude)
        color += float4(1, 0.5, 0, 1);

    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because `superEllipse(theta)` returns a point whose angle is not necessarily `theta`. For example, `superEllipse(3.6)` returns a point with an angle of 3.2 radians.
As a result, in your `main()` function, it doesn't really make sense to compare the magnitudes of `uv1` and `se`, since they have different angles.

See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YFr1.gif). The sweeping straight line represents the angle passed in to `superEllipse`, and the end of the curve represents where the new point is actually placed. Only rarely does the new point lie on the sweeping line.

If you use a polar equation for a superellipse, rather than a parametric equation, then you can use it to perform your distance test. Conveniently, [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipse.html) has just such an equation:

[image]

You just need to code that up and put it in your main function.

```
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{
    float2 uv1 = uv * float2(2.0f, 2.0f) - float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    float angle = degrees(atan2(uv1.y, uv1.x)) + 180.0f;
    //to do: implement equation shown above. Use `angle` for theta.
    //`m` should be 4 if you want a four-pronged shape.
    float magnitude = ??? 

    float2 zero = float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    float dist1 = distance(uv1, zero);
    float4 color = float4(0,0,0,1);
    if (dist1 <= magnitude) //uv is inside the superellipse
        color += float4(0,1,0,1);
    return color;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement it, (code is at the end of the question) but  M is incorrect for me, I really have to lower it to get a basic shape. The other thing I forgot to mention (updated the question too) is that I need to draw a rounded rectangle but apparently the Superformula doesn't do that, or does it ? references : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Comment: When you get the five-point star shape, what are your settings for M, N, A, and B? They should be 4, 0.5, 1, and 1. Also, you should take the absolute value of sin and cos - that's what the vertical bars indicate. The superformula should be able to draw any shape that the superellipse can, so rounded rectangles are possible

Comment: Also, watch your units for `mt`. In HLSL, do `sin` and `cos` want an argument in degrees, or radians? If it's radians, `angle` should just be defined as `atan2(uv1.y, uv1.x)`

Comment: Values were M = 0.9, N1 = 0.5 but using radians and absolute values, it's working now, thank you !